# No connection via Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a nodeJS app using soket io. This is my server code

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: verifyRequestSignature }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

var server = http.createServer(app);

var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var io = socketIO.listen(server);
io.set("transports", ["websocket"]); 



io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { 

  socket.on('test',function (message) {

    console.log(message)
  })
})
```

Then, when I want to connect the client via the Chrome plugin "socket.io tester", There is no connection and the server seem to work fine because there is not error logs.

I think the problem is the code in the server side.

Can you help me?

Comment: try using `http` module as listener, as mentioned on official docs
https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express

Comment: `var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);`

Comment: Thank @Theo It's Work. But When now localy! But when I upload the code of the server on heroku, it stop to work

Comment: cool! so it's listener issue. what port are you using? what do you mean by `stop to work`, did it crash or something?

Comment: I'm using the port 3000. I get this message on the console of the browser "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response"

Comment: i see. this is an entirely different story mate, you should post it in another thread and update me here so we can do another answer for that :) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177915/123123122

Comment: ok. I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion on OP comments, this appears to be an issue on how server listens for new connections. The one to listen for connections should be the **http** module, not the `express` module.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8080);
```

[See official express docs](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express)